# Include c++ files outside project directory in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, include

I have a problem regarding including files that are outside project directory (c). So I have a project in a workspace. There is a folder somewhere on my hard drive, containing a pair of .h and .c files. I would like to use them in several projects, that's why I wanted to place it outside the project.

I tried including this folder, .h file actually in many ways, but the compiler doesn't seem to see the content of it. I can successfully include the file, but the functions inside are not visible.

In the properties of the project -> C/C++ General -> Paths and symbols I have added the folder. What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add the relative path of all those `*.c` and `*.h` file.

```
#include "path_to_header/lib1.h"
#include "path_to_file/file1.c"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the same recently, here is what worked for me:

You have to mark the files as source code. Open project properties dialog and go to source location tab
[image]

then you can use Link Folder to select absolute path or you can use the variables to keep it relative to project file or workspace.
For other configurations Add folder was enough since they were already linked.

You also need to add include paths to c or c++ here
[image]

There probably already are some default paths so just add the new ones.
It can also be relative using variables.
I had more sub folders so I added them individually and did not use and relative path in #include at all.